# Prediction using historic data

Tags: distributions, predictive-models

I am looking for advice/guidance/recommendations on possible methods that could be used to estimate future events based on previous recorded data. I have an engineering background but relatively new to stats so have started with a few bits I found online.

I have the time taken to complete a task, occurring within the last three years, and would like to use this to inform the likely future time to complete the task with some confidence bands.

So far:

1. I have used a mixture of excel and R to analyse the data, calculate the IQR and remove any outliers from the analysis (+- 1.5*IQR) and then used `fitdistrplus` package to fit different distribution functions to the remaining data with `fitdist`. These include exponential, lognorm, normal, weibull, gamma and uniform; I then choose the distribution with minimum aic value as the optimum fit to that set of data. I then use the distribution parameters of the fit to produce a CDF curve and use a `rand' function in excel to choose a position on the curve and use the corresponding "hours" output. I would also like to include some kind of confidence interval but unsure how.
2. I have tried the bootstrap method on the whole dataset to incorporate the outliers as well. I then chose 200 repeats and found the mean for each repeat and the average of those 200 averages as well as the stdev. I then calculate an upper and lower confidence interval with `PERCENTILE.EXC(X3:X203,0.975)` and use a `norm.dist` function in excel to produce the CDF plot and generate values as before.

Any thoughts on the validity of these methods appreciated. A typical data set is inserted below.

```
5.5
12.5
6.25
5
13.5
10
9.25
11
3
6
4
3.5
9.25
8.75
9.75
5.5
8.75
5.75
6.25
1.75
9
4.25
6.25
3.5
8.25
17.75
11.25
4.25
9.75
10.5
7
3
4
5.75
6.5
9
6.75
8
4.75
1.75
4.5
8.25
3.5
7.75
10
6.25
6
7.75
11.5
7.5
9.75
4.25
8.75
9
6.75
7.25
4.75
7
3
0.5
5.5
5.5
3.5
3.25
5.5
5.5
5.5
11.5
7.5
4.5
8.25
8.5
8.5
6
7.25
9.25
2.75
5.25
8.75
1.5
6.5
9.5
3.75
5
3
8.5
5
5.5
7
6.5
4.75
6.75
4
7.25
2
14.5
9.5
8.25
5.5
8
10.25
10.25
7.25
11
6.75
7.75
5.25
4
1.75
8
10.5
9.25
8.75
5
5.25
10.25
10.25
3.75
9.75
4.5
6.25
12
7.5
6.5
9.75
4.25
5.75
9.75
7
3.75
4.5
8.25
4
12.5
1.5
40
39
19.5
53.25
44
19
228.75
21.5
40.5
63
20
18.25
24
20.25
19.5
22
52.25
22.5
20.5
39.25
```

Comment: I’ve removed the [tag:history] tag because this question is not about the history of statistics.

Comment: First insight, please add the date somewhere. Like starting date or ending date of the task. I think you need that to find if there is a trend for the project to be longer or faster as it goes. Then, If you don't have any more data than that. I would suggest to not use Big machine learning algo. Just the mean of the previous task could work. because nothing can help you to know if a task will be large or not

Comment: You could construct a kaplan meir curve quite easily from this data, which would give you the median time to completion + confidence intervals.

Comment: Why do you want to remove the "outlier" points? Andrew Gelman opposes outlier detection: https://statmodeling.stat.columbia.edu/2014/06/02/hate-stepwise-regression/.

Comment: The reason for removing outliers was to create an improved histogram for which to fit the different distributions against.

Answer (score 2):

A time-to-event (event = completition) approach as suggested by @DemetriPananos does indeed sound sensible. I'd be tempted to use a parametric survival model (e.g. a Weibull, although perhaps something more complex would make sense, if you have a lot of data) rather than the Kaplan-Meier, simply because it can somewhat sensibly extrapolate beydond the observed durations and if there's extra explanatory covariates, you could also incorporate them (including if there is truly a suggestion that something has changed - as suggested in another answer -, then that could be a covariate).

```
library(tidyverse)
library(survival)

example = read_csv("example.csv", col_names = F) %>%
  rename(time=X1) %>%
  mutate(status=1) 


sf1 = survfit(Surv(example$time, example$status) ~ 1)
plot(sf1)

sf2 = survreg(Surv(time, status) ∼ 1, dist="weibull", data=example)

tibble(time=c(0,sf1$time), surv=c(1,sf1$surv)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=time, y=surv)) +
  geom_step(direction="hv") +
  geom_line(data=tibble(time=seq(0,250,0.1), 
                        surv=1-psurvreg(time, scale=sf2$scale, mean=sf2$icoef[1])),
            col="red")
```

[image: Kaplan Meier plot and Weibull fit]

If you have prior information, you could also go Bayesian and incorporate it for a survival model (e.g. using the `brms` R package see [this vignette](https://wmbriggs.com/post/25849/)).

Comment: thanks for this, with my limited knowledge in this field, I dont really follow what you're method aims to show. Perhaps you have some reference to explain?
How would I use this kind of plot going forward? Say I wanted to predict a further 100 events occurring in the future, what time period would I allocate to them based on your plot?

Comment: The `psurvreg(t, scale=sf2$scale, mean=sf2$icoef[1])` function gives you what proportion of events you expect to have seen by time `t` (and 1-... what proportion is still expected to be event free).

Comment: im not sure this helps me. I am trying to predict the duration of a future event, not how long until the next event will occur. Can the survival analysis still be useful?

Comment: Not sure why this does not fit: You are basically considering the end of the event you are interested in as the "event" for the time to event analysis. Of course, the main reason to use a time to event approach (rather than just using, say, a Weibull distribution) is if some occurrences are not yet finished (or you only know they lasted for time t or longer).

Answer (score 1):

Well it looks like there is a changepoint (a point in which your data looks structurally different) around 135 data points in:

[image]

So any method which is fitting on the whole dataset here will have wonky intervals.  For example I can fit a mean changepoint model but it still calculates the intervals globally so the bands don't quite fit everywhere:

[image]

They are greatly overestimated for the first 135 periods.
So if all of your data looks similar to this dataset you may want to consider a simple changepoint method and calculate the corresponding bands within each changepoint.

Comment: thanks for that, but I dont think you should take the data in series, but think about each as a discrete event that happened on a historic date.

Comment: @phald is there something that occurred which accounts for the increase in value and variance?  Looks like it, possibly covid related?  I know you say not to view them as a series but just visually they look like you have 2 distributions you are pulling from where the mean and variance of the second is the result of some shock.

Comment: No reason that I am aware of. The values are the number of hours required to complete a task. In theory the same task each time. No particular reason why one event should take 228 hours, maybe they were waiting for something to be delivered or repaired

Comment: The reason the data appears to be two distributions is because they were separated into outliers & non-outliers using the IQR calculation. The larger values at the end of the series were the values I planned to exclude as they fell outside 1.5*IQR.

Comment: @phald ah gotcha, then I ignore my answer! Thought it ordered by time.